# Function execution is not stopping after matching condition in for-loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, for-loop, do-while

> my node req and res, I want to stop execution after matching condition, however its doing whole operation pushing array and sending double response

```
Router.post('/api/friend-req', async (req, res)=>{
    try{
        let newDate = new Date().toISOString();
        const bodyData = req.body;
        let requestList = await User.findOne({_id:bodyData.friend_id}, ['requests']);

        for(var i = 0; i < requestList.requests.length; i++){

            if(requestList.requests[i].friend == bodyData.user_id){
                await res.json({error:'requests alreay sent'});
                break;
//its doing below operation even after matching my codition and sending double response
            };
        };
//this will be done only when condition does not match
        requestList.requests.push({
            friend: bodyData.user_id,
            addAt: newDate
        });
        
        const storeUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:bodyData.friend_id}, {requests: requestList.requests});

        res.json({success:'req sent successfuly'});
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: `break` only exits the loop. So any code after the `for` loop will run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
return res.json({error:'requests alreay sent'});
```